# Opening .pkt (Omnipeek capture) file in C

Tags: c, wireshark, pcap

I would like to open an omnipeek (.pkt) file in a C program. How do I do it? Conversion to .pcap and opening via pcap library results in loss of important radio information. Can I have a sample program which reads a .pkt file offline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Wireshark is a sample program that does that, albeit a large one.  See the wiretap/peekclassic.c file for the "classic" Peek format (used in older versions of WildPacket's software) and wiretap/peektagged.c for the "tagged" Peek format (used in current versions of their software).

You might want to handle more radio information in the "tagged" format than Wireshark currently handles.

Answer (score 0):

WildPackets tech support can provide you with documentation of the file format. Also, recent versions of OmniPeek will include the radio information when saving in pcap format.